# What is the purpose of using cors in express.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Used cors in express.js,but I am not clear about this.What is the purpose of using cors in express.js ?

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0):

Cross-origin(cors) resource sharing allows ajax requests to skip the Same-origin policy and access resources from remote hosts. Cors is use as a Intermediary. To communication  to different port.